# Firebase FCM giving result "error":"InvalidRegistration"

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, post, firebase-cloud-messaging

This is the function i am using to request the result using kotlin coroutine.

```
private fun sendNotificationToUser(boardName: String, token: String): String {
        var result: String

        var connection: HttpURLConnection? = null
        try {
            val url = URL(Constants.FCM_BASE_URL)
            connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection

            connection.doOutput = true
            connection.doInput = true
            connection.instanceFollowRedirects = false
            connection.requestMethod = "POST"
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")
            connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8")
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json")
            connection.setRequestProperty(Constants.FCM_AUTHORIZATION, "${Constants.FCM_KEY}=${Constants.FCM_SERVER_KEY}")
            connection.useCaches = false

            val wr = DataOutputStream(connection.outputStream)

            val jsonRequest = JSONObject()
            val dataObject = JSONObject()
            dataObject.put(Constants.FCM_KEY_TITLE, "Assigned to the Board $boardName")
            dataObject.put(Constants.FCM_KEY_MESSAGE, "You have been assigned to the new board by ${mAssignedMembersList[0].name}")

            jsonRequest.put(Constants.FCM_KEY_DATA, dataObject)
            jsonRequest.put(Constants.FCM_KEY_TO, token)

            wr.writeBytes(jsonRequest.toString())
            wr.flush()
            wr.close()

            val httpResult: Int =
                connection.responseCode

            if (httpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                val inputStream = connection.inputStream
                val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))
                val sb = StringBuilder()
                var line: String?
                try {
                    while (reader.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n")
                    }
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                } finally {
                    try {
                        inputStream.close()
                    } catch (e: IOException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }
                result = sb.toString()
            } else {
                result = connection.responseMessage
            }

        } catch (e: SocketTimeoutException) {
            result = "Connection Timeout"
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            result = "Error : " + e.message
        } finally {
            connection?.disconnect()
        }

        return result
    }
```

Can anyone please tell me what could be the possible reasons behind me getting this error and how can one resolve those different error.

This is the end result that i am getting ->
{"multicast_id":4389386151184574869,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}